# Removing appendix header after the end of appendix

Tags: header-footer, appendices

I would like to insert my personal acknowledgements by means of a `\chapter*{acknowledgements}` command after the end of appendix.
I created the appendix in the usual manner, with `\appendix` or `\begin{appendices}-\end{appendices}` but, since my acknowledgements are spread along three pages, on the third one of ack. chapter there is the appendix header on the top displaying the appendix title.
How can I remove it? It seems that TeX thinks that acknowledgements chapter still is an appendix chapter.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,openright,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

immediately following the line

```
\chapter*{acknowledgements}
```

insert this command:

```
\markboth{Acknowledgements}{Acknowledgements}
```

you may have to input this in all caps to match the running head style for the rest
of your document.

some document classes don't make proper running heads from the titles when entered
with `\chapter*`, and it appears that you're using one of them.

Comment: Wouldn't be useful to put before the `\chapter*{Acknowledgments}`, the `\backmatter` macro?

Comment: @Aradnix -- it's a judgment call whether `\chapter*{Acknowledgments}` should be placed after `\backmatter`.  (i wouldn't ordinarily, but i can understand why others might.)  in any event, it wouldn't help fix the running heads -- that is *definitely* a consequence of the documentclass-specific design.